# Why introducing a field into my Grails domain breaks hasMany relationships

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have hit a grey cell teaser that I'm really struggling to understand, hopefully the answer lies here.

I have a Grails domain model that involves subclassing, associations, subclassed assocations and until now everything was working fine.

My domain is similar to this..

```
class AssocationRecord
  static belongsTo = [MasterRecord]

class AssocationRecordB extends AssocationRecord
    // other fields

class MasterRecord
  hasMany associations:AssocationRecord

class MasterRecordB extends MasterRecord
  hasMany associations:AssocationRecordB
```

This model was working fine,  I could have subclasses special versions of the main records as designed and all was well until... until I wanted to introduce a single AssociationRecord into MasterRecord such that the domain became:

```
class MasterRecord
  AssocationRecord favouriteAssociation

  hasMany associations:AssocationRecord
```

With that introduction, and once the field had a value, I could break the code, simply by trying to access the collection in an instance of MasterRecordB

such as:   MasterRecordB.first().associations.each() {}

That would fire a MissingMethodException exception (below)

I see the references to javaassist, could this be a clue as to what's gone wrong?

If I remove the new field,  everything goes back to working as expected.  I'm considering storing an ID for the field rather than the object but it doesn't help understand why I'm seeing this behaviour.

Thanks,

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1$_run_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (mypackage.AssociationRecord_$$_javassist_109) values: [mypackage.AssociationRecordB : 22777]
Possible solutions: doCall(mypackage.AssociationRecordB), call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call(mypackage.AssociationRecordB), findAll()
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:273)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
  at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:4)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:518)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:556)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:527)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$evaluate.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
  at org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleService.eval(ConsoleService.groovy:37)
  at org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleService$eval.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
  at org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleController.execute(ConsoleController.groovy:36)
  at org.grails.plugins.console.ConsoleController.execute(ConsoleController.groovy)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.invoke(OriginalClassInvoker.java:47)
  ...
```